# Clear placeholder text from storyboard or XIB outlets

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, xib, nib

In my XIB file and storyboards I have some UILabel's with placeholder text that I would like to clear out before the view loads.

Is there some function provided by the SDK for this purpose?

What is best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect each UILabel to correspond IBOutlet variable in your code and change the text of it on early stage of view's lifecycle.

```
@IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel! // connected in xib

override func viewDidLoad() {
    someLabel.text = ""
}
```

Comment: Does the SDK provide for a prepareStoryboard function? This is what I'm doing now but it seems sort of - you know - unprofessional to do it like that. Is there a "clean" way?

Comment: If you need to clean all the labels in Storyboard you can do this by opening it as source code (right click) and use find and replace to clean it. but, anyway, you need to setup labels somehow later...

Comment: So the user has to wait for the API to return with data - during this time the placeholder text is showing. I'm looking for a graceful way to clear it out before the view appears. Is there one? Clearing it out in viewDidLoad isn't so graceful IMHO. Perhaps there is a best practice for this? I want the placeholder text so I can clearly see what's going on in the Storyboard.